# Trilinear interpolation in HOG

Tags: image-processing, feature-extraction

I am currently implementing HOG in Matlab, but I don't understand the binning, especially the trilinear interpolation part.

What I understood is, that each pixel in a cell is dropped into a bin to form the histogram for this cell. But that's all I understand atm.

1. How is the magnitude computed?
2. What are the edges of the cube, and what are the 3D coordinates for one pixel?

Comment: you check his [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Zib1YEE4LU) for a crystal clear idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_gradient) describes the gradient (in the context of images) and shows how to obtain its `x` and `y` coordinates.

> How is the magnitude computed?

```
r = sqrt(x*x+y*y)
```

> what are the 3D coordinates for one pixel?

When computing the gradient, the image is considered as a height map. For a pixel at a position `(x,y)` with a gray scale value `z` it represents the height map 3D position `(x,y,z)`.

A gradient at `(x,y,z)` has an orientation and magnitude. The histogram is a discretization of all possible orientations into bins. For example with 8 bins, all orientations from 0 to 45 degrees will be associated to the same bin.

The selection of bins is based on the gradient orientation and a weight is added to the bin based on the magnitude.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients) describes the steps of HOG and gives details pointers in the original paper.